# AMS Euler and italic variables

Tags: chemistry, physics, euler

I prefer using the beautiful AMS Euler math font, but - as we all know - it is only upright. I was wondering that there were so few complaints about this fact. In Germany there's even a DIN standard saying that variables should be written italic. Until now, I didn't find any peer-reviewed chemical or physical journal without italic variables. Are here any chemists or physicists using this font? How do you deal with this regulations and constraints?

Comment: It’s very simple: don’t use Euler fonts if you must have italic variables

Comment: This is more a question directed at the maintainer or designer of the font in question, I think. Only if there is a German standard, it does not mean that every font has to provide the characters defined therein.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hermann Zapf is unfortunately deceased. However, one workaround would be to load Euler for upright variables and constants, and some other font, such as his Palatino or Optima, for slanted ones.

Comment: @Davislor Well, there might be other designers who pick up his great work and create an italic style for the required glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

If your publisher or supervisor doesn’t let you use an upright font, you can’t use Euler.

One possible compromise is to use Euler for upright symbols (I’m not sure what your requirements are, but in ISO 80000, constants are upright) and a compatible font for slanted ones.  Palatino and Optima, also designed by Hermann Zapf, might be good choices to match Euler.  Khaled Hosny, who converted Neo Euler to OpenType shortly before Zapf passed away, has also made a text font based on Euler, [Aref Ruqaa,](https://github.com/aliftype/aref-ruqaa) but it is upright only.  If you also need a monospace font to match these, I recommend Inconsolata.  Another option is the font AMS Euler was originally paired with, AMS Concrete.  (Donald E. Knuth commissioned both fonts together for his book, *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*.)

My go-to example is typesetting Euler’s identities with the constants in Neo Euler and everything else in a Palatino clone:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler + TeX Gyre Pagella sample]

A version that works with PDFTeX would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgpagella, newpxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{euler}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{euler}{bold}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upe}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"65}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"69}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
```

A variation of this would be to load Euler Math as the main math font, including its symbols, and then the `it` and `bfit` alphabets only from some other math font, such as TeX Gyre Pagella Math, Asana Math or Concrete Math.